# Send Short cut command to other application in c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pywin32, user32

Hi I am developing an application (A) in c# that will use other application (B) which is running in try mode in the background. I want to send some short cut commands to application (B) from Application (A) by pressing a button on Application (A) I have following code behind the button:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
// public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr handleParent, IntPtr handleChild, string className, string WindowName);


[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

public const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
public const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;
public const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0102;
public const int VK_SHIFT=10;
public const int VK_A = 0x41;

public void sendShortcutsToOneScreenConnect()
{
     Process[] process1 = Process.GetProcessesByName("NameOfTheProcess");
     process1[0].WaitForInputIdle();
     IntPtr handler = FindWindow(null,"Tittle Of The Window ");
     SendMessage(handler, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_A, VK_SHIFT);          
}
```

I am getting "0" handler of this window . And can some body tell me is this right approach to this thing ? I don't want to bring Application (B) window to foreground .

Comment: The FindWindow portion looks good - verify that the title of the window is correct

Comment: It Application B is another app you have developed then if you embed a WCF service within it, it will make it very easy to run any remote command from application A.